# Where can I find a list of all available address_component values?

Tags: google-places-api

The [Place Details Responses](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) provides an example of the address_component array, however it isn't inclusive of every possible option that can be returned. If I want to construct an actual address that includes all of the lesser-known address elements (e.g., pre-direction, post-direction), how can I determine what those options are?

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have already implemented/tried. This question is too broad.

Comment: It's not a problem with code. To clarify, some address return a Floor value for businesses that occupy an entire floor. If I do a query for a home address, the Floor property isn't included. I'm looking for documentation of the available address_component values so I know what to look for in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the directionals are at least included in the route property. Maybe the sample result does contain all of props?